# All the possible errors of a django Form (ModelForm)?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I would like to know what is the comprehensive list of all possible errors that can arise when doing the form.is_valid() in a ModelForm (ex. ValueError)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `form.is_valid()` should only raise a `ValidationError` and no other exceptions. If you're getting other errors that means you're using custom fields which aren't adhering to this convention.

Django's standard fields all catch exceptions and then raise a `ValidationError` to make it possible to handle that when calling `is_valid()`. In other words, you should look into the code of the custom fields that your model is using and fix their validation code to raise only a `ValidationError`.